# How to throw errors in Next.js App Router so will be shown in browser network tab

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have been getting up to speed with Next App Router lately whilst developing my app. Page Router had this elegant looking code where all components were rendered client side and props generated server side and fed as props to client component if and when needed e.g. getServerSideProps.

I need to replicate similar scenario as per below

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://...');
    const data = await response.json();

    // Customize the response status based on conditions
    const statusCode = response.status !== 200 ? response.status : 404;

    return {
      props: {
        data,
        statusCode,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      props: {
        data: null,
        statusCode: 500,
      },
    };
  }
}
```

I suspect this can be extended here, check and throw other errors 403, 502 etc.

How do I get it in Next App Router, for the life of me I am only getting 200 or 500

So I have a helper function with or without commented block

```
import { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes'

export default async function getApi(
  url: string,
  params: RequestInit | undefined = undefined,
) {
  try {
    const response: Response = await fetch(url, {
      cache: 'no-store',
      ...params,
    })

    // if (!response.ok) {
    //   return {
    //     status: response.status,
    //   }
    // }

    const json = await response.json()

    return { json, status: response.status }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      status: StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
    }
  }
}
```

For the sake of testing I stick to fetch not my getApi (but would appreciate comments if anything can be improved there to have reusable function)

So in my getIsValidIP function below I fetch API KEY from endpoint using server side function getAccessToken. I read from header my IP. Both are provided to my response call, has to be on legit IP with correct Bearer token. As a response I expect to see { valid: true/false } and 200-OK

Now I want to handle some errors for my client side component, I thought by returning them as per each if statement in my function I get errors I need in the network tab, instead I see 200-OK all the time, sometimes 500

```
import { StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes'
import { headers } from 'next/headers'

import getAccessToken from '@/app/actions/getAccessToken'
import { API_VALIDATION } from '@/app/constants'

export async function getIsValidIP() {
  const accessToken = await getAccessToken()

  const header = headers()
  const ip = (header.get('x-forwarded-for') ?? '127.0.0.1').split(',')[0]
  const ipNoSubnetPrefix = ip.split(':').pop()

  const response = await fetch(`${API_VALIDATION}?ip=${ipNoSubnetPrefix}`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`, // if dummy token, 401 error => handled as 520 below
    },
  })

  const res = await response.json()

  if (response.status === StatusCodes.OK && res.valid) {
    return { valid: res.valid, status: StatusCodes.OK } // 200
  }

  if (response.status === StatusCodes.OK && !res.valid) {
    return {
      message: 'You do not have permission to access this resource.',
      status: StatusCodes.FORBIDDEN, // 403
    }
  }

  if (response.status !== StatusCodes.OK) {
    return { message: 'Something went wrong.', status: StatusCodes.BAD_GATEWAY } // 502
  }
}
```

In my page I consume the above in the following way

```
import { getIsValidIP } from '@/app/actions/getIsValidIP'
import { SomeComponent } from '@/app/some/component'

export default async function SystemStatusPage() {
  const response = await getIsValidIP()

  if (response?.status !== StatusCodes.OK) {
    return <div style={{ padding: '10px' }}>{response?.message}</div>
  }

  return <SomeComponent />
}
```

It does what it supposed to in terms of messages, but I see nothing in network tab, relevant 502, 403 which should have been thrown with message